# .NET Core ChannelFactory - Set a X509Certificate2 as Client Certificate

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core, client-certificates

I need to set a client certificate (as instance, not from windows certificate  store) to my wcf channel, but I always get the Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Object is read-only."

This is strange, because the these properties have a setter but if I assigned a X509Certificate2 is crashes.

### Stacktrace

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Nachricht = Object is read-only.
  Quelle = System.Private.ServiceModel
  Stapelüberwachung:
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.ThrowIfImmutable()
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.set_DefaultCertificate(X509Certificate2 value)
```

### Code

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://myservice.com"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

var token = GetToken(); // Just an method that reads a pfx from disk
channelFactory.Credentials.
    ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = token.Certificate; // throws exception
channelFactory.Credentials.
    ClientCertificate.Certificate = token.Certificate; // throws exception too
```

### Update 1

The method `SetCertificate` throws the same `System.InvalidOperationException: "Object is read-only."` exception.

```
using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)) 
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    var x509Certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, token.Certificate.Thumbprint, false);
    if(x509Certificate2Collection.Count == 0)
        store.Add(token.Certificate);
}

channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My,X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, token.Certificate.Thumbprint);
```

### Update 2

The implementation of [X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Security/X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.cs) is interesting.

```
public X509Certificate2 DefaultCertificate
{
    get
    {
        return _defaultCertificate;
    }
    set
    {
        ThrowIfImmutable();
        _defaultCertificate = value;
    }
}

internal void MakeReadOnly()
{
    _isReadOnly = true;
    this.Authentication.MakeReadOnly();
    if (_sslCertificateAuthentication != null)
    {
        _sslCertificateAuthentication.MakeReadOnly();
    }
}

private void ThrowIfImmutable()
{
    if (_isReadOnly)
    {
        throw DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new InvalidOperationException(SR.Format(SR.ObjectIsReadOnly)));
    }
}
```

**Something** is calling `internal void MakeReadOnly()` and make so my life harder.

Comment: What's `GetToken()`? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: It would already help if you replaced `var` with the actual type on the line with GetToken().

Comment: And I remember a ClientCertificate.SetCerticate(...) method, do you see that here and does it work? List any dead ends you tried.

Comment: And can't you find out who calls that? Because the reason would also point to a way around it. There are s many ways to set up these certifcate and credential types.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Found it https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/a2c95ad9e5cb2fff465655ae234454cf6f1c0f83/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Description/ClientCredentials.cs#L185

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While reading the `ClientCredentials.cs` on github, I found the method  [`MakeReadOnly()`](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/a2c95ad9e5cb2fff465655ae234454cf6f1c0f83/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel/Description/ClientCredentials.cs#L185).

The call of `channelFactory.CreateChannel()` makes the ClientCertificate instance read-only, so after change the order of the statements it works!

## Working ClientCertificate Authentication with WCF:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://myservice.com"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding, endpoint);
// Must set before CreateChannel()
channelFactory.Credentials.
    ClientCertificate.Certificate = token.Certificate;

var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
```